# HList with unary constrain to varargs cast

Tags: scala, shapeless

Let's say we have this:

```
def join[A, B](a: A, b: B)
def join[A, B, C](a: A, b: B, c: C) // etc
```

Basically a lot of overloaded methods for up to 20 type arguments.

And then the following which is creating a K-list by enforcing an unary type constraint on the `HList` such that all inner elements are of type `Task[_]`.

```
class Test(L <: HList : *->*[Task]#λ](val deps : L = HNil)
```

Is it possible to convert the `deps` to a `Task[A1, A2, A3]` etc where the `A1`, `A2`, `A3` are the inner types of the `HList`?

So for:

```
val hls = Task(1) :: Task("string") :: Task9(true) :: HNil
```

Retrieve a:

```
Task[(Int, String, Boolean)]
```

And do this for any number of arguments? I can convert a `Task[A], Task[B]` to a `Task[A, B]` for any number of arguments already, just need to get from `HList` to `varargs` or similar.

Comment: @TravisBrown This is currently a Twitter Future joined with `Future.join`. The new `Futures.join` overload could presumably be re-written  to an `HList` friendly version for the purpose of my exercise but I don't know enough about shapeless ops to go from HList to Tuple to varargs and get the type.

Comment: Ah, sorry—reading too quickly. Using the overloaded `join` methods probably isn't practically, but it's possible to use nested pairwise calls to `join`—I can put together an example this evening if nobody beats me to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Scala's perspective those `join` methods don't have anything in common but their name, so it's not really possible to use them in this context without a lot of boilerplate (or a custom macro). Instead it's possible to use the `join` on Twitter's `Future` itself repeatedly. You can do this by creating a new type class:

```
import shapeless._

trait FutureSequence[L <: HList] extends DepFn1[L]
```

This type class will witness that an hlist `L` is made up entirely of futures, and it will give us a way to sequence those futures into a `Future[T]`, where `T` is the tuple made up of the types inside of each of the futures in `L` (the `*->*` gives us the first part of this, but doesn't support the second, or even any way to do the second part at all conveniently).

The companion object does all the interesting work:

```
import com.twitter.util.Future
import shapeless.ops.tuple.Prepend

object FutureSequence {
  type Aux[L <: HList, Out0] = FutureSequence[L] { type Out = Out0 }

  implicit def hnilFutureSequence: Aux[HNil, Future[Unit]] =
    new FutureSequence[HNil] {
      type Out = Future[Unit]
      def apply(l: HNil): Future[Unit] = Future.Unit
    }

  implicit def hconsFutureSequence[H, T <: HList, OutT](implicit
    fst: Aux[T, Future[OutT]],
    pre: Prepend[Tuple1[H], OutT]
  ): Aux[Future[H] :: T, Future[pre.Out]] = new FutureSequence[Future[H] :: T] {
    type Out = Future[pre.Out]

    def apply(l: Future[H] :: T): Future[pre.Out] =
      l.head.join(fst(l.tail)).map {
        case (h, t) => pre(Tuple1(h), t)
      }
  }
}
```

We're using induction here—first we describe how to sequence `HNil` (our base case), and then we describe how to sequence `Future[H] :: T` given that we know how to sequence `T`.

Next we'll define a method to make this easy to use:

```
def sequence[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit fs: FutureSequence[L]): fs.Out = fs(l)
```

And then if we've got some examples:

```
 val good = Future(1) :: Future("string") :: Future(true) :: HNil
 val bad = Future(1 / 0) :: Future("string") :: Future(true) :: HNil
```

We can sequence them:

```
scala> import com.twitter.util.Await
import com.twitter.util.Await

scala> Await.result(sequence(good))
res0: (Int, String, Boolean) = (1,string,true)

scala> sequence(bad).onFailure(println)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
res1: com.twitter.util.Future[(Int, String, Boolean)] = ...
```

You could also require a `FutureSequence` instance in your class's constructor, or on specific methods on your class.

Comment: It was either you or Miles who could answer this, and I know Miles is hard to reach. Many thanks for taking the trouble, this is indeed beyond really cool

Comment: I'm not hard to reach ... It's @travisbrown who's incredibly quick off the mark! :-)

Comment: @travisbrown is there a contib equivalent for cats? I'm wondering if I could get this for free if the unary constraint was `Option`. Seems I'm googling and only ever coming back to my own questions, which means I never learn